# Is it wrong to say "someone is always trying hard to do something"?

Tags: grammar

I'm doubtful if the following sentence is true and makes sense in English. It's actually intended as a dedication. I searched the internet but found very few similar examples. Should I have used present simple in this context?

> To Betty, a clever girl who is always trying hard to achieve success!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either tense is just fine here. I think there might be some idiomatic problems, though, unrelated to the verb tense.

I'm guessing that you mean this sentence to be a compliment, to say that Betty is hard-working, focuses on the goal of her work, and is often successful. One problem is that "try" can also communicate just attempting something, and especially failing. "Trying" focuses on the effort that the person puts forth: "It doesn't matter that you failed; at least you tried your hardest." There's even a book called *Trying Hard is Not Good Enough*!

This meaning is intensified by adding "to" and a goal. "Trying hard to ___" tends to communicate trying unsuccessfully. A bird who is "trying hard to fly" suggests one that is putting forth a lot of effort but is still on the ground. All together, "always trying hard to achieve success" suggests that, even though Betty keeps on trying so hard, bless her heart, she just can't achieve success.

There are many other wordings that could communicate the opposite; maybe:

- "... a clever girl who is always working hard toward achievement and success!"
- "... who is always hard at work and successful in all she does!"
- "... who always gives her utmost to achieve success!"

Comment: Your alternative sentences are much better, but I have already sent the message! Do you mean my sentence is nowhere near a compliment? What do you think about a similar sentence by someone who got a PhD from an English university? "Elijah is a very conscientious student who is always trying hard to achieve results both in his personal and professional life."

Comment: Well, your intent to honor Betty is clear, and I'm sure she understands exactly what you mean for it to say. (I'd still have the same suggestion for the PhD's sentence, though!)

Comment: @Beatsme - references are sometimes written in a deliberately ambiguous style, especially, perhaps, if a negative message is intended. If I were someone considering Elijah for a job, and I read that, I might call the professor on the phone. I once had an applicant for a job and his last manager had written "You will be very lucky if you get John Smith to work for you."